# Can you avoid unboxing in a memoizing generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, boxing, memoization

I have a generic method I use to memoize conversions of string values in the db to an actual converted value.

```
public MySpecialValue {
    object val;
    bool valSet = false; 

    T GetValue<T> () { 
         if (!valSet)
         {
                val = (T)Convert.ChangeType(DatabaseValue, typeof(T));
                valSet = true;
         }
         return (T)val;
     }

     public string DatabaseValue { get; set; }
}
```

The trouble is that during initialization I do not know what type the data in the database is, its only on first call that I can make this decision.

Is there any way to structure it in such a way that it is not forced to unbox value types that are cached? (without changing the signature of the containing class)

Comment: I don't really see any way to do it without making  `DoSomethingExpensive` generic.

Comment: I guess I could code gen an action and store it ... but I am betting its more expensive to call then unboxing

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't necessarily show any (un)boxing. Could you provide a bit more context (and code) showing what's going on in the containing class?

Comment: @LukeH ... added the missing vars.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense to me. Where is "rawVal" coming from? How does DoSomethingExpensive know that it is supposed to return a T for some arbitrary T?

Comment: @Eric ok changing this to the concrete sample

Comment: So what happens when this method is called twice, once with "int" and once with "string"? This is still not making any sense to me; why is the method generic in the first place?

Comment: @Eric ... that can not happen, not part of the design, it is only ever called with one type. Its happening cause I need to load up all the existing values for these "settings" from the DB, in a single batch, before I know what type they are.

Comment: @Eric, Its generic cause later on ... after stuff is loaded from the db ... a helper generic method calls it ... Eg: 'Get<int>("MyMagicalIntSetting", default: 2);'

Comment: If it's only ever called with one type then it's not *generic*. Why doesn't it just return an int if it is always called with the type argument "int"?  I think you're having difficulties here because you're abusing the type system.

Comment: @Eric ... I doubt not there is abuse ... and in retrospect the .net type of the "configuration settings" should probably have been stored in the DB and thus this mess could be avoided.  ... but the underlying implementation I am replacing allows for interchangeable types based on setting name eg: `Get("Site.ReadOnly", default: false);` is allowed ... and so is `Get("Site.Twitter.AccountName", default: "");` ... a fix the rips out the underlying callers is way out of scope for my current round

Answer (score 5):

The code you give is somewhat bizarre. How does "DoSomethingExpensive" know to return a T *for arbitrary T*?  That makes no sense to me.

The way you typically write a generic memoizer is like this:

```
public static Func<T> Memoize(this Func<T> func)
{
    bool executed = false;
    T result = default(T);
    Func<T> memoized = ()=> 
    {
        if (!executed)
        {
            result = func();
            executed = true;
        }
        return result;
    };
    return memoized;
}
```

And now you can say:

```
Func<int> expensive = DoSomethingExpensiveThatGetsAnInt;
Func<int> memoized = expensive.Memoize();
```

And you're done. No boxing required.

Comment: Eric ... I agree it is a bit bizarre ... but it has a crazy little use case for us: in our code it is `(T)Convert.ChangeType(DatabaseValue, typeof(T))`

Comment: @Sam: I think the question would make a lot more sense if you posed the problem that you actually have rather than trying to make a weird abstract version of it.

Answer (score 3):

If T and the result of `Convert.ChangeType` are reference types then there will be no unboxing.

If `Convert.ChangeType` returns a boxed value type and T is a value type then there isn't anything you can do to avoid unboxing if you want GetValue to return T.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `Lazy<T>` for this.

So if you have some kind of collection of properties.

```
public class MyClass 
{
...
}

Public class MyClass<T> : MyClass
{
  T val;
  bool valSet; 
  public T GetValue<T> () { 
        if (!valSet)
        {
            val = (T)Convert.ChangeType(DatabaseValue, typeof(T))};
            valSet = true;
        }
        return val;
    }
}
```

Presumably you then have a generic method in your parent class

```
class SomePropertyBag{

private Dictionary<string, MyClass> dict;

T GetValue<T>(string name, T default)
{
  MyClass res;
  if(!dict.TryGetValue(out res))
  {
     res = new MyClass<T>(name);
     dict.Add(name, res);
  }
  return ((MyClass<T>)res).GetValue();
}
```

Comment: Not if val and valSet are private. You don't have to expose the Lazy<T>, you can use it internally.

Comment: this kind of breaks for me, I need to be able to put MyClass in a dictonary ... before knowing the type it will eventually contain ...

Comment: @Sam - I didn't have the original problem 100% when I wrote this - I see your predicament. I was assuming that SomeLongRunning guy was going to be only dependent on the property name passed in, and no on previously fetched data. That leaves you with 2 dictionaries to implement it this way or your previous way - which is cleaner. NB you can get rid of your valSet private and replace it with a check for nullness of your val container - since in the case of a null actual value you will havean actual container holding null :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to bet (OK, I also have the advantage of having the source code...) that in most cases this code is called as per you your examples in [your reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730838/can-you-avoid-unboxing-in-a-memoizing-generic-method/4731207#4731207)

```
Get("Site.Twitter.AccountName", "")
```

or

```
Get("Site.Twitter.AccountName", 77)
```

In which case you are using generic type inference. But there is another, simpler, thing that would compile there... **don't use generics**. I expect there are only a few scenarios here; so **write** a few classes / method-overloads - one for `string`, one for `int`, etc.

```
string Get(string key, string defaultValue) {...}
int Get(string key, int defaultValue) {...}
bool Get(string key, bool defaultValue) {...}
```

Sure, there will be a *little* duplication, but the compiler will be able to optimise for each individual scenario - no boxing. You could even (if you choose) replace the `Convert.ChangeType` with something like `int.Parse` (for the `T = int` case).

---

Another option (given your examples) is to make the memoized object generic:

```
public MySpecialValue<T> {
    T val;
    bool valSet = false; 

    T GetValue() { 
         if (!valSet)
         {
                val = (T)Convert.ChangeType(DatabaseValue, typeof(T));
                valSet = true;
         }
         return val;
     }

     public string DatabaseValue { get; set; }
}
```

and push the `<T>` code up a level, so that is done in a cast.

Answer (score 0):

This makes stuff ever so slightly faster for value types (no unboxing) ... and ever so slightly slower for ref types one extra call ... it is however a bit strange.

```
 class MyClass {
    class Container<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }

    bool valSet;
    object val; 

    public T GetValue<T> () { 
        if (!valSet)
        {
            val = new Container<T>{Value =  (T)Convert.ChangeType(DatabaseValue, typeof(T))};
            valSet = true;
        }
        return ((Container<T>)val).Value;
    }

    public string DatabaseValue { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: This is of course a pretty brittle piece of code. If you call GetValue<int>() and then later call GetValue<string>() you will get an exception. Of course it is difficult to know if that is an issue withing this context.

Comment: @Neil, for my context: if somebody does: `Get(setting: "Site.Twitter.AccountName", default:"");` followed by a `Get(setting: "Site.Twitter.AccountName", 77);` ... I actually want stuff to explode

Comment: Sure - sounds reasonable. Then in that case though the whole of the MyClass could have been generic.  I will edit my answer to reflect.

Comment: see added code in my answer - I put it there because it is easier to talk code.